# Changing Workspace background in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I was looking for **changing the workspace background of MS Word**.

Now, I don't want to change the page-background colour.

We can see the custom workspace colour in **View>Notebook-Layout / Publish-Layout**; but how to change the same in **Print-layout**.

Comment: What version of Word is in question?

Comment: @techie007~ Office 2011.